# Inject http into httpProvider in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to make it so that users are automatically logged out by having the client terminate the session (as opposed to letting the session die on its own).  I pushed an interceptor onto the $httpProvider which allows me to set and reset the timeout timer, but the problem is that I can't figure out how to call the logout function which requires $http.  This always produces a circular dependency.  Is there any way to do this?

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(
    function() {
      return {
        response: function(response) { $http({ ... }); }
      })}
```

If I make $http a dependency, I get a circular dependency, but without the $http dependency, the call to $http obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be careful using $http inside an interceptor as it has the potential to cause an infinite loop. Consider refactoring so $http isn't required

That said you can try injecting the $injector instead. Then where you want to make the $http request just use `$injector.get('$http')`

```
app.config(['$httpProvider, $injector', function($httpProvider, $injector) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(
    function() {
      return {
        response: function(response) { $injector.get('$http') }
      })}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject `$http` dependancy inside the`inceptor.push` function, you could also inject other dependencies from there.

**Code**

```
app.config(['$httpProvider',
    function($httpProvider) {
       $httpProvider.interceptors.push(
         function($http) { //<--here you could make dependency available.
           return {
             response: function(response) {
               $http({...});
             }
           })
         }])
```

Comment: Maybe for other services, but injecting the service inside its provider gives me an error `Circular dependency found: $http <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state`

Answer (score 0):

I used a crossover of the previous answers (use $injector, but in the push() ) to get it working as expected:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $injector) {
      ...
      //now get $http like this and use it as needed:
      $injector.get('$http')
```